# Apache fails with self-assigned SSL and MAMP Pro 5

Tags: apache, ssl, mamp-pro

My self-assigned SSL key/crt were working fine in MAMP Pro 4. Ever since I upgraded to MAMP Pro 5, Apache fails to run if any host has a self-assigned SSL. I've tried the obvious solutions like removing/adding the host and deleting/creating new crt/keys, but nothing has seemed to work.

Anyone else have the same issue or fix?

Comment: You need to enable the Apache `ssl` module --  In Linux it's `sudo a2enmod ssl` --  Not sure how to do it in Windows.

Comment: Actually, that's not the problem. It is enabled. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Prior to MAMP Pro 5, you had to specify a secure port number of 8890 under the General tab of the host settings. Now if you do, Apache will fail to start up. So, you need to remove the port number in order to make Apache work again.